# Equally Spacing Containers within Parent Container without Grid/Flex

Tags: html, css

I wanted to see if anyone could help me understand what I am failing to understand when I try to equally space four child containers within a single parent container, without Flex/Grid as I have not yet gotten to the point where I covered those topics.

My approach was to create a parent container with a set width, set each of the child containers to be 25% width of the parent container, and then use text-align:center to center the 'content' with those child containers. I have my HTML & CSS below. I have also included a screenshot of the results in-browser.

```css
.parent-container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.alignment-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="parent-container">
    <div class="alignment-container"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="alignment-container"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="alignment-container"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="alignment-container"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[Code Output in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogcpv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You want the content div to be inside the alignment-container container, but the problem here is that you have the content as a div on itself - it has no relationship with the alignment-container.

so change your code from this:

```
<div class="alignment-container"></div>
                <div class="content"></div>
```

to:

```
<div class="alignment-container">
                <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```